# Username or display name search in documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to know how I can search for a username or display name with two different columns, without case sensitive capitalization or accents.

For a simple search I use this code:

```
try {
        var re = new RegExp(`${Letter}`);
        var users = await UserModel.find({ name: { $regex: re, $options: 'i' }, disabled: false });
    } catch(err) {
        return res.json({
            "code": err.name,
            "message": "Une erreur est survenue"
        })
    }
```

However, this code doesn't work if there is an accent, and I can't find any way to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example for your document and the expected output?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vi50fx

For example, I can search for the user via "username" or/and "blaze" partially or completely. However, I don't want the "blaze" part to be case sensitive by capitals, lowercase letters and accents.